# How to create JSON object in the jsp page

Tags: json, class, struts, action

I am developing a web application in struts 1.3 , I have a situation that I have a grid and some contols on the jsp page ,say I have one dropdown list, one textfield , one add button and one submit button now my requirement is that on selecting some value from dropdownlist,putting some value in textfield and on pressing add button it should temporary get displayed into grid 
and for that I have thought of using JSON object when user presses the add button a javascript function should call and put that data into JSON object and on submitting the form I should get that JSON object into my Action class (Struts) or server side to manuplate it and finally save it into Database.

Comment: if any answer help u, don't forget to accept that answer....

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example you may take a look at. Basically your JSP page might look like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("title", "TITLE_TEST");
    json.put("link", "LINK_TEST");
    System.out.print(json);
    System.out.flush();
%>
```

also look this:-

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question right, you need to pass the JSON values as the object of a class(which I will be referring as a MOdel class).

For that you can do something like this.

```
var Model=new Array();
Model['attribute1']=<value from any element in the form>
Model['attribute2']=<another value obtained from the page>

var param=JSON.stringify(Model);
```

Now the param variable is in fact JSON format of an object of Model class.

Make sure that the fields attribute1 and attribute2 are variables of the class to which you need to read the form data. Also, the variables need to be spelt right.

You can change the signature of the method which gets invoked when the form is submitted, to accept an object of the Model class.

I am not sure of the syntax for the method signature when using Struts. But have done something similar when working in Spring. Hope this helps